# What is the most robust way to make http request

Tags: .net, performance

I usually use this approach to make sure all http classes are properly disposed and nothing is left hanging in memory:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://xxxx") as HttpWebRequest;
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
  using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    ... do my stuff ...
```

Any better idea?

Comment: Whats your problem? This looks good...

Comment: Technically, only one using statement is required as they both just dispose the stream. They won't hurt though and you are safe if this implementation changes in future.

Comment: HttpWebRequest doesn't have a Dispose method so the using clause on it does nothing.

Comment: @Steve, I don't see any using around the `request`. What's your point?

Comment: Why did you talk your question as `performance`, but then didn't mention performance in any way in your question?

Comment: @svick - My eyes betrayed me: I thought there was a using around the request.  I would delete my comment but you have already responded to it.

Comment: given http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803945/what-is-the-most-robust-way-to-open-file-and-read-content this looks like a "fake" quesions to me just trying to get rep.

Comment: These are the two most common areas of memory leaks and IO performance bottleneck. Thus looking for suggestion to improve this. I don't care about stackoverflow rep. Look at my profile to see why