# What is the most robust way to open file and read content

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I usually do this when I have to read the whole file always:

```
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(...))
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
     var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Any better/faster way?

Comment: given http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803937/what-is-the-most-robust-way-to-make-http-request, this looks like a "fake" quesions to me just trying to get rep.

Comment: These are the two most common areas of memory leaks and IO performance bottleneck. Thus looking for suggestion to improve this.
I don't care about stackoverflow rep. Look at my profile to see why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"your file path");
```

If you want to get lines:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"your file path");
```

if you want to only read lines until get to some line then use the IEnumerable ReadLines:

```
foreach(string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"your file path")
{
    if (line == ...)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was actually looking for a robust way. Do you know if those methods are 100% robust and does not leak anything? I am happy to write more lines of code than using shorthands.

Comment: @Omar: I think Microsoft make those `shorthands` using the best practice, also when you are using these methods you will have all updates and improvements when you update the framework too.. however you can check there code using programs like `Reflector`, for instance Microsoft`s version of  `ReadAllText` method is just similar to yours: `    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
`

Comment: Thanks Jalal. So ReadAllText forces UTF8 encoding. That answers some of the problems I had with encoding.

Comment: Yes that is true, not only `ReadAllText` uses `UTF8` but also `ReadAllLines` and `ReadAllLines` also uses it.